# Error in Python Code Trying To Open and Access a File

Tags: python

Here is info from the .txt file I am trying to access:
****Movies: Drama****
Possession, 2002
The Big Chill, 1983
Crimson Tide, 1995

Here is my code:

```
fp = open("Movies.txt", "r")  
lines = fp.readlines()
for line in lines:  
    values = line.split(", ")   
    year = int(values[1])
    if year < 1990:  
        print(values[0])
```

I get an error message "IndexError: list index out of range". Please explain why or how I can fix this. Thank you!

Comment: your first line in the file is ```Movies: Drama``` There is no `,` in this. So when you split at `lines.split(', ')` the resulting list is just one entry that says: `['Movies: Drama']. So `values[1]` will be  list index out of range

Comment: The first line of your file does not contain a comma, therefore the `.split()` returned a list with only one element, there `values[1]` does not exist when processing that line.  One solution would be to do `header = fp.readline()` just after opening the file, so that the main `for` loop never sees that line.

Comment: When I changed the .txt file and got rid of what you said, it worked. THANK YOU

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Your first instinct when you get an error message should be to read it, and try to understand it. The error message will tell you which line of code caused the problem (here, trying to do `values[1]` failed), and why (`[1]` is the index; it is "out of range"; therefore, `values` doesn't have enough elements in it for there to be a `[1]` to access). From there, you work backwards (`values` was determined by `line.split(", ")` - so, what did that do?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your .txt file includes the "Movies: Drama" line, as you listed, it's because the first line of the text file has no comma in it.  Therefore splitting that first line on a comma only results in 1 element (element 0), NOT 2, and therefore there is no values[1] for the first line.

It's not unusual for data files to have a header line that doesn't contain actual data.  Import modules like Pandas will typically handle this automatically, but open() and readlines() don't differentiate.

The easiest thing to do is just slice your list variable (lines) so you don't include the first line in your loop:

```
fp = open("Movies.txt", "r")
lines = fp.readlines()
for line in lines[1:]:  
    values = line.split(", ")   
    year = int(values[1])
    if year < 1990:  
        print(values[0])
```

Note the "lines[1:]" modification.  This way you only loop starting from the *second* line (the first line is lines[0]) and go to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the text file does not have a ", ", so when you split on it, you get a list of size 1.  When you access the 2nd element with `values[1]` then you are accessing outside the length of the array, hence the `IndexError`.  You need to do a check on the line before making the assumption about the size of the list.  Some options:

1. Check the length of `values` and `continue` if it's too short.
2. Check that ', ' is in the line before splitting on it.
3. Use a regex which will ensure the ', ' is there as well as can ensure that the contents after the comma represent a number.
4. Preemptively strip off the first line in `lines` if you know that it's the header.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of your txt file has wrong index
Just simple change your code to:

```
fp = open("Movies.txt", "r")  
lines = fp.readlines()
for line in lines:  
    try: #<---- Here
        values = line.split(", ")   
        year = int(values[1])
        if year < 1990:  
            print(values[0])
    except: #<--------And here
        pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).